# Jquery, on click on header, open panel body

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this panel:

```
<div class="panel">
        <div class="panel-heading" style="cursor:pointer"> blablabla
            <div class="pull-right"><a href="#" data-perform="panel-collapse"><i class="ti-plus"></i></a> <a href="#" data-perform="panel-dismiss"></a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-wrapper collapse" aria-expanded="true">
            <div class="panel-body">
                unicorn
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

---

I've wrote this jquery:

```
<script>
    $('.panel').on('click', function() {
        $(this).children().toggleClass('panel-wrapper collapse, panel-wrapper collapse in');
    });
</script>
```

But this close the panel, no matter where I'm clicking it. Now I only want that the panel opens, if I click on the panel-heading. ( The **whole** panel heading, currently the panel only opens if I click on that small `<i> icon` )

and If I click the panel again, it should get closed again.

`<div class="panel-wrapper collapse **in**">` would be a closed panel. Without the `in` in collapse in, the panel is closed.

I hope somebody can help me there. And I'm sorry for my bad english.

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Can you create the plunker for your code ? But I think you should change `toggleClass('panel-wrapper collapse, panel-wrapper collapse in');` to `toggleClass('in');` .

Comment: No I can't :/ Thats a template and I don't have the javascript code for the whole panel thing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `next()`

```js
$('.panel-heading').on('click', function() {
        $(this).next('.panel-wrapper').toggleClass(' in');
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="panel">
        <div class="panel-heading" style="cursor:pointer"> blablabla
            <div class="pull-right"><a href="#" data-perform="panel-collapse"><i class="ti-plus"></i></a> <a href="#" data-perform="panel-dismiss"></a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-wrapper collapse" aria-expanded="true">
            <div class="panel-body">
                unicorn
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

You can use `slideToggle("slow")` to slide in the panel slowly or make use of -webkit transitions in css.

```js
$('.panel-heading').on('click', function() {
        $(this).next('.panel-wrapper').slideToggle("slow");
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="panel">
        <div class="panel-heading" style="cursor:pointer"> blablabla
            <div class="pull-right"><a href="#" data-perform="panel-collapse"><i class="ti-plus"></i></a> <a href="#" data-perform="panel-dismiss"></a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-wrapper collapse" aria-expanded="true">
            <div class="panel-body">
                unicorn
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I think your code would run better then the code snippet from @Spencer Rohan. But thanks to you both :)

Comment: Happy To help : ) . And yes Spencer solution is also good but if you can directly access an element why go for different approach

Comment: Is there a way to open the panel smoothly? Now it just opens. It isn't necessary but would be awesome. I'm still learning jquery..

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri It's super late here, you're right -- I put down an answer and then said, oh wait -- next() would be a way to go. You beat me to the punch.  WellNo look into http://api.jquery.com/slidedown/

Comment: @WellNo  You can use slideToggle() . I have updated my post

Comment: I've tried slideToogle() before. This works but if I click the first time on the panel-heading. The panel automatically opens and closes again. Only after that it really works.

Comment: Thats a little strange.  It didn't happen with me. I think than you can use custom webkit transitions in a class and toggle that to

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.panel-heading').on('click', function() {
    $(this).parent().children().toggleClass('in');
});
```

Comment: I think you can clean this up using siblings() or next()

Answer (score 0):

Thhis might be what you want I guesss

```
 <script>
        $('.panel-heading').on('click', function() {
            $(this).children().toggleClass('panel-wrapper collapse, panel-wrapper collapse in');
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: I've tried the same thing before but this did nothing. Because The Panel-wrapper collapse class isn't a child from the panel-heading

Comment: Is there more than 1 panel heading?